# How can I define a structure that will contain two multidimensional unconstrained arrays an pass it to a procedure

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada so, I have a question: How can I define a structure that will contain two multidimensional unconstrained arrays an pass it to a procedure.
Following the code that I have wrote:

```ada
package SDR_Treatment is
   
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   --  CONSTANTS                                                               -
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   
   GEO_SPACIAL_AND_SPEED: constant Natural :=  1;     --Type of Data
   
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   type Slicing_Pointers is  array (Positive range <>) of Integer;
   type Region is array (Positive range <>, Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Integer;
   
   type Location_and_Speed_Region is record
      
      Region_Id : Natural := 0;
      SP: Slicing_Pointers;
      Rig: Region;
      
   end record;
   
   procedure SDR_Encoding(lsr: in out Location_and_Speed_Region);
   

end SDR_Treatment;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The package body:**

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;

package body SDR_Treatment is
   
   procedure SDR_Encoding(lsr: in out Location_and_Speed_Rigion) is
--      lsr : rig;
   begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Encoding SDR...");
   end SDR_Encoding;
   
end SDR_Treatment;
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

**This is the error that i have got from compiler**

```
 C:\GNAT\2017\bin\src\sdr_treatment.ads
        18:11 unconstrained subtype in component declaration
        19:12 unconstrained subtype in component declaration
```

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler says, you can't declare record components with unconstrained subtypes.

You have to fix the constraints as a part of the record declaration:

```ada
package SDR_Treatment is

   type Slicing_Pointers is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;
   type Region is array (Positive range <>,
                         Positive range <>,
                         Positive range <>) of Integer;

   type Location_and_Speed_Region (Low    : Positive;
                                   High   : Natural;
                                   X_Low  : Positive;
                                   X_High : Natural;
                                   Y_Low  : Positive;
                                   Y_High : Natural;
                                   Z_Low  : Positive;
                                   Z_High : Natural) is
      record
         Region_ID : Natural := 0;
         SP        : Slicing_Pointers (Low .. High);
         Rig       : Region (X_Low .. X_High,
                             Y_Low .. Y_High,
                             Z_Low .. Z_High);
      end record;

end SDR_Treatment;
```

Comment: Moreover, I would provide a kind of constructor to provide preconditions on the parameters. This would avoid creating null arrays when, for example, _X_Low_ is greater than _X_High_

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for an answer. I did exactly as you have showed but the compiler exited with the following messages: gprbuild -ws -c -f -u -PC:\GNAT\2017\bin\training.gpr sdr_treatment.ads
Compile
   [Ada]          sdr_treatment.ads
cannot generate code for file sdr_treatment.ads (package spec)
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
[2018-05-16 16:22:28] process exited with status 4, elapsed time: 05.41s. I don't understand what is wrong!?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  The compiler just gives you a slightly confusing message.  What it says is that it will not generate any object code for the package, which is perfectly sensible, since it doesn't declare any operations (except an implicit `function "="`).

Comment: Once you add some subprogram specifications to the package specification, the compiler will look for a package body and try to generate object code.

Comment: Actually, Jacob, your code compiles just fine. If it won’t compile for Sasha, then his code isn’t the same as yours. Sasha, as Jacob indicated, this message normally means that the package _requires_ a body (e.g., there’s a subprogram declared in the spec). Indeed, if the spec _doesn’t_ require a body, it’s illegal to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

You should think your declaration as C arrays in

```ada
type Location_and_Speed_Region is record
    Region_Id : Natural := 0;
    SP: Slicing_Pointers;
    Rig: Region;
end record;
```

Here, you're trying to declare a record where the size of its static components is not known at compile time which is almost the same as declaring

```c
struct {
  char int[];
};
```

If you want it to be more "dynamic" while avoiding using accesses (i.e. pointers), take a look at *[discriminated record](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/record#Discriminated_record)*.

If you prefer something using dynamically allocated memory, use *[access
 types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access)*